# Showing that a subset of a set of functions is closed.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

I'm an undergraduate with little to no background in functional analysis and topology. The whole concept of function spaces is quite fuzzy to me, and I'm having a difficult time conceptualizing it. (Things like there being different notions of compactness in general topological spaces is one of many things confusing me because of what I've learned so far. I have learned many things which turn out to be true only in metric spaces, or in $\mathbb{R}^n$ specifically.)

Consider the following situation:

Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $[a, b] \subset \mathbb{R}$. Let $F$ denote the set of all functions from $A$ to $[a, b]$, and $G \subset F$ denote those functions which possess a particular attribute that we are interested in.

In order to finish a larger proof, I'd like to show that $G$ is closed; later on, I want to work with pointwise convergence of functions in $G$. Since we are dealing with a function space, I'm a bit unsure about how to do this, because I'm uncertain about what constitutes a limit point in this space.

I have showed that, for any sequence $(f_n)_1^\infty$ of functions in $G$ converging pointwise to some $f \in F$, $f$ must be in $G$. I believe that this shows that $G$ is closed, and I believe that it has to do with the connection between the product topology and pointwise convergence of functions, but I would really appreciate feedback on this; have I misunderstood what "closed set" means in this context?

Thanks!

EDIT: In my case, $G \subset F$ is the set of all functions $f:A \rightarrow [a, b]$ such that $f(a) + f(b) + f(c) = c(f)$, for any three pair-wise orthogonal unit vectors $a, b, c$, where $c(f)$ is a constant depending only on $f$.

Second attempt: Take any function $f \in F \setminus G$. There exist two sets of orthogonal unit vectors $(v_1, v_2, v_3)$ and $(v_4, v_5, v_6)$ such that
\begin{equation*}
\Delta = \left| \sum_{i=1}^3 f(v_i) - f(v_{i + 3}) \right| > 0.
\end{equation*}
The set
\begin{equation*}
B_{\Delta/6} = \{ f \in F : \max(|f(v_i) - g(v_i)|) < \Delta / 6, i = 1, 2, \dots 6 \}.
\end{equation*}
is an open neighborhood of $f$. Take any $g \in B_{\Delta/6}$, and let $\delta_i = g(v_i) - f(v_i)$, for $i = 1, 2, \dots 6$, so that $|\delta_i| < \Delta / 6$. We get
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\left| \sum_{i=1}^3 (g(v_i) - g(v_{i+3})) \right| = \left| \sum_{i=1}^3 (f(v_i) + \delta_i - f(v_{i+3}) - \delta_{i+3}) \right| \geq\\
\left| \sum_{i=1}^3 (f(v_i) - f(v_{i+3})) \right| - \left|\sum_{i=1}^3 (\delta_{i+3} - \delta_i) \right|
= \Delta - \left|\sum_{i=1}^3 (\delta_{i+3} - \delta_i) \right| > \Delta - \Delta = 0,
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
using the reverse triangle inequality. Thus $g \in F \setminus G$, so that $B_{ \Delta / 6} \subset F \setminus G$, meaning $F \setminus G$ is open. We conclude that $(F \setminus G)^C = G$ is closed.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What norm are you using?

Comment: If your demonstration of the fact that every $(f_n)\in G^{\mathbb N}$ converges for the topology in $F$ to some element $f\in G$, then your start is fine. In general, a topology on a set of functions is defined by a norm, so make sure your "pointwise" convergence can be converted in a convergence for this norm.

Comment: Is there a norm usually associated with the product topology? Basically, I want to show that $G$ is closed, so that it is compact (being a closed subset of the compact set $F$) in the product topology.

The functions I'm interested in (making up $G \subset \mathbb{R}^3$) are those functions $f$ such that $f(v_1) + f(v_2) + f(v_3)$ equals some constant for any three orthonormal vectors $v_1, v_2$ and $v_3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have shown is that $G$ is *sequentially closed*, which may not imply that $G$ is *closed*. The two concepts coincide for metric spaces, but not in general.

Here is a standard counterexample which fits your situation as well: if $A = \mathbb{R}, a=0,b=1$, and $G$ is the set of all functions $f:A\to [0,1]$ such that $f(x) = 0$ for all but countably many $x\in A$.

This set is sequentially closed because the countable union of a countable set is countable. However, it is not closed in $F$ : If $g\in F$ is any function, and $U$ is a basic open neighbourhood in the topology of point-wise convergence, then $\exists x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n\in A$ and $\epsilon > 0$ such that
$$
U = \{f\in F : |f(x_i) - g(x_i)| < \epsilon \quad\forall 1\leq i\leq n\}
$$
Now simply that $f\in G$ such that $f(x_i) = g(x_i)$ for all $1\leq i\leq n$ and $f(x) = 0$ if $x\notin \{x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n\}$. Then $f\in U$, so $U\cap G\neq \emptyset$. Hence, $g\in \overline{G}$.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I think I have a better understanding of what constitutes an open set in the product topology now, and have updated my post with a second attempt at a proof. If you have time to look at the edit, it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: @DoppeDee: The edit looks good to me!

Comment: Thank you. I'll mark your answer as accepted since you showed what I had done wrong.

Answer (score 3):

If you are considering functions from $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ to $[a,b]$ in the pointwise topology, then for a condition like you describe in the comments: $f(v_1) +f(v_2) + f(v_3) \in C$ where $C$ is closed in $[a,b]$ (like a singleton or a finite set maybe), then the functions that satisfy it is indeed closed. To show this it does *not* suffice to consider sequences from this set, but nets will do, if you know about them.

Otherwise let $F = \{f :A \to [a,b]\}$ in the pointwise (=product  ) topology and set $D = \{f: A \to [a,b]: f(v_1) + f(v_2) + f(v_3) \in C\} = (s \circ  p_v)^{-1}[C]$, where $p_v : F \to \mathbb{R}^3, p_v(f) = (f(v_1), f(v_2), f(v_3))$ is continuous as a projection and $s: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}: s(x,y,z) = x+ y +z$ are both continuous and the inverse image of a closed set under a continuous map is closed.

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't quite clear in that comment. What I meant is that these functions are of the form $f : A \rightarrow [a, b]$ such that $f(v_1) + f(v_2) + f(v_3) = c(f)$, where $c(f)$ is a constant depending only on $f$, and not on the choice of orthogonal unit vectors.

Perhaps your argument still applies? The value $c(f)$ is in the set $[3a, 3b]$, and for any point in $[3a, 3b]$ there exists a function on the form above (the constant function $f(x) = c \in [a, b]$, for example), and $[3a, 3b]$ is closed relative to itself.